# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: interaction is not defined

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord.js

I made a discord bot that edit peoples profiles, but it came out like this.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: interaction is not defined

I'm new to programming

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const Canvas = require("canvas");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args)=> {

  const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(256, 256);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const background = await Canvas.loadImage(interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' }));
  ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage('./bars.png');
  ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 0, 200, canvas.height )

  const attachment = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'jailxd.png');

  message.channel.send(attachment);
  }

  exports.conf = {
    enabled: true,
    guildOnly: true,
    aliase:["catch"]
}

exports.help = {
    name:"jail",
    description:"Empty",
    usage:"jail",
    category:"fun"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to make common text command and not slash command, so instead of [`interaction.user.displayAvatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) you need to use [`message.author.displayAvatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL)!

```js
const background = await Canvas.loadImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' }));
```